# Stripping AMCL TF Tree for Robot_Localization

Tags: navigation, transform, robot-localization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying the run robot_localization's ekf node with amcl and odometry as the inputs. I would like the ekf node to perform a transform from map->odom. Right now both amcl and the ekf node are performing the map->odom transform and this is causing the robot, in simulation, to shake: jumping back and forth between the two estimates. Is there a way to block amcl from publishing the tf transform while still providing information to the ekf node?

I have tried remapping tf to a different name but this also blocks the /amcl_pose topic which is needed for the ekf node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255713/stripping-amcl-tf-tree-for-robot_localization/) by [Nicholash Bedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29465/nicholash-bedi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julio Aguilar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29550/julio-aguilar/) on 2017-03-08**:
Hi there,

were you able to start a robot_localization's ekf node with amcl and odometry? I haven't been able to. My ekf instance doesn't publish the right transform. It filters the odom frame even though I specified world_frame as map_frame. Did you do something else besides blocking the amcl tf?

**Comment by [Nicholash Bedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29465/nicholash-bedi/) on 2017-03-08**:
Hi,
You also need to make sure map_frame, odom_frame, and base_link_frame are set appropriately. Additionally, publish_tf should be set to true. What do you mean by "filters odom"? Do you have a direct map to base_link transform? or no Map or odom frame at all?

**Comment by [Julio Aguilar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29550/julio-aguilar/) on 2017-03-08**:
Hi, could you look at http://answers.ros.org/question/256504/yet-another-problem-with-robot_localization-and-amcl/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nicholash,

you just need to change the parameter 'tf_broadcast' to false in your config file of the amcl filter. That should stop the filter from broadcasting the map->odom transfrom.

---

Originally posted by [Julio Aguilar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29550/julio-aguilar/) with karma: 56 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3